# Indexes are not using when I join in Sybase

Tags: indexing, sybase, using

QUERY:

```
select    b.cusip   
from    StanDb..bond_identifier b, EnigmaDb..cpm_filter c
where   b.identifier_code = c.identifier_code
and     b.identifier_value like c.identifier_value
```

Indexes:

```
create unique nonclustered index cpm_filter_idx01 
on EnigmaDb.dbo.cpm_filter(identifier_code, identifier_value)

create unique clustered index x1 
on StanDb.dbo.bond_identifier(cusip, identifier_code)

create nonclustered index x2 
on StanDb.dbo.bond_identifier(identifier_code, identifier_value)
```

Query Plan:

QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 1 (at line 1).

```
STEP 1
    The type of query is SELECT.

    FROM TABLE
        EnigmaDb..cpm_filter
        c
    Nested iteration.
    Table Scan.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning at start of table.
    Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.

    FROM TABLE
        StanDb..bond_identifier
        b
    Nested iteration.
    Index : x2
    Forward scan.
    Positioning by key.
    Keys are:
        identifier_code  ASC
        identifier_value  ASC
    Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for index leaf pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for index leaf pages.
    Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
```

Execution time: 0.028 seconds

My question is here is second table in join query is using full table scan instead of index scan.

Could some one please help me understanding this.

Comment: How big is the second table?  The optimizer will also take into account the number of rows in the table when deciding it's plan.

Comment: can you try `and     b.identifier_value = c.identifier_value` instead of `and     b.identifier_value like c.identifier_value`